# pageBaseType in Web.config on IIS6

Tags: c#, web-config

I am currently defining a base class for my views which itself inherits System.Web.UI.Page. This new class exposes new properties to be defined through the @Page directives.

On IIS 7 (.NET 4), registering this new base class in web.config as

```
<page pageBaseType="newPageClass">
```

works very well, though on IIS 5.1 (XP, .NET 3.5) it fails, forcing me to revert to also specifying

```
CodeFileBaseClass="newPageClass"
```

directly in each view.

The target server will eventually be IIS 6, which I cannot test right now. So I have a couple of questions:

1) Is this related to the IIS version, and if so will it work on IIS 6?

2) Is this related to the .NET version, and if so, at what version does this web.config override become available?

3) Is it something completely unrelated to these two possibilities.

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to .NET 2.0 so nothing to do with IIS itself.  I would verify that the target framework on IIS 5.1 is indeed set to 2.0 and not 1